# Plotly not showing stacked chart values

Tags: pandas, charts, plotly, stacked

I am trying to plot a grouped/stacked chart. It was working fine with 3 values but not more. [image]The stacked chart does not show all values. Some are overlapped. Looking for expert advice to solve this problem! is there other python libraries that I can use for the same thing. Please see the code below. Thank you very much!

```
from plotly import graph_objects as go

data = {
    "mes":[m18parish_tot, 23, 32, 10, 23],
    "sles":[sl18parish_tot, 23, 32, 10, 23],
    "dutches":[dutch18parish_tot, 23, 32, 10, 23],
    "enebes":[eneb18parish_tot, 23, 32, 10, 23],
    "nwppes":[nwpp18parish_tot, 23, 32, 10, 23],
     "cwes":[cw18parish_tot, 23, 32, 10, 23],   
    "oes":[o18parish_tot, 23, 32, 10, 23],
    "res":[r18parish_tot, 23, 32, 10, 23],
     "ues":[u18parish_tot, 23, 32, 10, 23],
    "nwsbes":[nwsb18parish_tot, 23, 32, 10, 23],     

    "mhs": [m18parishhs_tot,   8, 18,  6,  0],
    "slhs": [sl18parishhs_tot, 18, 18,  0,  20],
    "mec": [m18parishec_tot,   8, 18,  6,  0],
    "slec": [sl18parishec_tot, 18, 18,  0,  20],
    
     "bhes":[bh18parish_tot, 23, 32, 10, 23],

    "labels": [
        "2018-2019",
        "2019-2020",
        "2020-2021",
        "2021-2022",
        "2022-2023"
    ]
}

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Bar(
            name="Manhattan ES",
            x=data["labels"],
            y=data["mes"],
            text=data["mes"],
            offsetgroup=0,
        ),
        
        go.Bar(
            name="Staten Island ES",
            x=data["labels"],
            y=data["sles"],
            text=data["sles"],
            offsetgroup=0,
            base=data["mes"],
        ),
        
        go.Bar(
            name="East/NorthEast ES",
            x=data["labels"],
            y=data["enebes"],
            text=data["enebes"],
            offsetgroup=0,
            base=data["mes"],
        ),
       go.Bar(
            name="Dutchess ES",
            x=data["labels"],
            y=data["dutches"],
            text=data["dutches"],
            offsetgroup=0,
            base=data["mes"],
        ),
      go.Bar(
            name="Northwest ES",
            x=data["labels"],
            y=data["nwppes"],
            text=data["nwppes"],
            offsetgroup=0,
            base=data["mes"],
        ),


            
        go.Bar(
            name="M3 HS",
            x=data["labels"],
            y=data["mhs"],
            text=data["mhs"],
            offsetgroup=1,
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="SL HS",
            x=data["labels"],
            y=data["slhs"],
            text=data["slhs"],
            offsetgroup=1,
            base=data["mhs"],
        ) ,
        go.Bar(
            name="M3 EC",
            x=data["labels"],
            y=data["mec"],
            text=data["mec"],
            offsetgroup=2,
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Sl EC",
            x=data["labels"],
            y=data["slec"],
            text=data["slec"],
            offsetgroup=2,
            base=data["mec"],
        )
    ],
    layout=go.Layout(
        title="",
        yaxis_title="Actual Enrollment",
        xaxis_title="Years"
    )
)
fig.update_xaxes(type='category')
fig.update_yaxes(dtick=500)
fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, 9000])
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')

fig.show()
```

Comment: I feel like the range of the chart and the difference in data is the problem – for the `2018-2019` category, the values for individual bars are in the thousands, but for all the other year ranges onward, your stacked bars don't exceed the first tick mark at 500. Can you show an example of how this was working fine when there were three values? And also what would your desired output be? Even if the text didn't overlap, you wouldn't be able to distinguish one bar from another unless you zoomed in. From a visualization perspective, it might be best to separate `2018-2019` in a different figure

Comment: Data type of 2018-2019 is string not numeric values, this is a problem and you cannot plot it.

Comment: I added the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

- Remove the data of 2018-2019 since they are string and not numeric values.
- The manual range of y-axis is too large compared with the values, therefore you could not read the values inside each bar. The solution is to remove the manual range and let it be automatically customized based on the values.

**The full code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from plotly import graph_objects as go

data = {
    "mes":[23, 32, 10, 23],
    "sles":[ 23, 32, 10, 23],
    "dutches":[23, 32, 10, 23],
    "enebes":[ 23, 32, 10, 23],
    "nwppes":[ 23, 32, 10, 23],
     "cwes":[23, 32, 10, 23],   
    "oes":[ 23, 32, 10, 23],
    "res":[ 23, 32, 10, 23],
     "ues":[23, 32, 10, 23],
    "nwsbes":[ 23, 32, 10, 23],     

    "mhs": [ 8, 18,  6,  0],
    "slhs": [ 18, 18,  0,  20],
    "mec": [  8, 18,  6,  0],
    "slec": [ 18, 18,  0,  20],
    
     "bhes":[23, 32, 10, 23],

    "labels": [
        "2019-2020",
        "2020-2021",
        "2021-2022",
        "2022-2023"
    ]
}

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Bar(
            name="Manhattan ES",
            x=data["labels"],
            y=data["mes"],
            text=data["mes"],
            offsetgroup=0,
        ),
        
        go.Bar(
            name="Staten Island ES",
            x=data["labels"],
            y=data["sles"],
            text=data["sles"],
            offsetgroup=0,
            base=data["mes"],
        ),
        
        go.Bar(
            name="East/NorthEast ES",
            x=data["labels"],
            y=data["enebes"],
            text=data["enebes"],
            offsetgroup=0,
            base=data["mes"],
        ),
       go.Bar(
            name="Dutchess ES",
            x=data["labels"],
            y=data["dutches"],
            text=data["dutches"],
            offsetgroup=0,
            base=data["mes"],
        ),
      go.Bar(
            name="Northwest ES",
            x=data["labels"],
            y=data["nwppes"],
            text=data["nwppes"],
            offsetgroup=0,
            base=data["mes"],
        ),


            
        go.Bar(
            name="M3 HS",
            x=data["labels"],
            y=data["mhs"],
            text=data["mhs"],
            offsetgroup=1,
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="SL HS",
            x=data["labels"],
            y=data["slhs"],
            text=data["slhs"],
            offsetgroup=1,
            base=data["mhs"],
        ) ,
        go.Bar(
            name="M3 EC",
            x=data["labels"],
            y=data["mec"],
            text=data["mec"],
            offsetgroup=2,
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Sl EC",
            x=data["labels"],
            y=data["slec"],
            text=data["slec"],
            offsetgroup=2,
            base=data["mec"],
        )
    ],
    layout=go.Layout(
        title="",
        yaxis_title="Actual Enrollment",
        xaxis_title="Years"
    )
)

fig.update_layout(barmode='group')

fig.show()
```

**Output**
[image]